# Como fazer mais de um select no field para jaspersoft

Tags: jasper, jaspersoft-studio

Preciso criar dois selects. Um para o total e outro para trazer todos os campos. Como que eu faço para colocar 2 selects na query da criação dos campos?

preciso que ele some este total:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: Preciso fazer outro select aqui]

Comment: crie um select só onde você traga todos os campos e junto um count para trazer o total do que você deseja

Comment: Poste o comando SQL que você precisa

Comment: @R.Santos eu preciso fazer um somatório ali daqueles valores. Já tentei com sum, mas ele só retorna um único valor.

Comment: Poste o comando SQL ,não a imagem assim fica mais fácil ajudar

Comment: SELECT SUM(pedidos.total), pedidos_id , pedidos.cliente_id , pedidos.produto_id , clientes.nome AS nome_cliente , produtos.nome AS nome_produto , produtos.preco as preco_produto, pedidos.data , pedidos.frete , pedidos.quantidade, pedidos.total FROM pedidos INNER JOIN clientes ON pedidos.cliente_id = clientes.clientes_id INNER JOIN produtos ON pedidos.produto_id = produtos.produtos_id GROUP BY pedidos.pedidos_id ORDER BY clientes.nome;

Comment: No caso você quer que em todas as linhas o valor total seja o mesmo isso?

Comment: Sim eu quero que ele mostre o total e crie uma outra coluna com o subtotal. Mas pensei em fazer diferente em outra consulta. Por isso eu preciso saber fazer outro select naquele jasper. Dai ficaria fácil de fazer o relatório. Tipo fazia um select para todos os inner joins e depois outro para trazer o total dos valores da coluna total.

Comment: Tente um subselect para trazer no valor total, eu por exemplo tenho uma tabela `estoque` onde tem o codigo do suprimento seu numero de serie e o valor unitario de cada um, fiz assim: `select codigosuprimento, numeroserie, valorunitario, (SELECT SUM (valorunitario)
 FROM public.estoque where usado = '0' and codigosuprimento = 155 group by codigosuprimento) as total FROM public.estoque where usado = '0' and codigosuprimento = 155;` para trazer o valor total desse suprimento com seu valor unitario

Comment: Não precisa. Deu certo já. Ficou assim a consulta: SELECT pedidos_id , pedidos.cliente_id , pedidos.produto_id , clientes.nome AS nome_cliente , produtos.nome AS nome_produto , produtos.preco as preco_produto, pedidos.data , pedidos.frete , pedidos.quantidade, pedidos.total, (SELECT SUM(pedidos.total) FROM pedidos) AS sub_total FROM pedidos INNER JOIN clientes ON pedidos.cliente_id = clientes.clientes_id INNER JOIN produtos ON pedidos.produto_id = produtos.produtos_id GROUP BY pedidos.pedidos_id ORDER BY clientes.nome

Comment: Ah que bom que deu certo, postei uma resposta para que se alguém tiver a mesma necessidade tenha mais facilidade para encontrar a resposta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após sugestão de subselect a query ficou assim:

> SELECT pedidos_id , pedidos.cliente_id , pedidos.produto_id ,
>   clientes.nome AS nome_cliente , produtos.nome AS nome_produto ,
>   produtos.preco as preco_produto, pedidos.data , pedidos.frete ,
>   pedidos.quantidade, pedidos.total, (SELECT SUM(pedidos.total) FROM
>   pedidos) AS sub_total FROM pedidos INNER JOIN clientes ON
>   pedidos.cliente_id = clientes.clientes_id INNER JOIN produtos ON
>   pedidos.produto_id = produtos.produtos_id GROUP BY pedidos.pedidos_id
>   ORDER BY clientes.nome